# Login Facebook android studio error

Tags: android, facebook

I create app login Facebook and when I click button login it show error

```
onErrorCaught exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sat Oct 01 17:05:09 GMT+07:00 2011, validation time: Thu Aug 28 07:00:00 GMT+07:00 2014
```

How I can fix it?
My code sample is tutorial in [Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your phones date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Add Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
}
```

Add button to layout

```
        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add bellow functions to Activity Class

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton facebookLoginBtn;

 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            jsonToMap(response.getJSONObject());
                            String uniqueId = map.get("id");
                            String userName = map.get("name");
                            String mail = map.get("email");
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            UIHelper.informDialog(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.unable_to_sign_int));

        }
    };

 public void initAllSignSdk() {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);

    }

 private void initViews(Dialog login) {
        facebookLoginBtn = (LoginButton) login.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        facebookLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
        facebookLoginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }
```